# Why the Browse button is always disabled in the Location tab of an Active Directory Object properties

Tags: active-directory

I can sense the purpose of the Location tab in an Active Directory object, I know I can set the information manually but the fact there's a Browse button next to it tells me there's maybe a way to predefine the whole "location tree" one time for all.

If my assumption is correct, how can it be done?

Comment: What in the where, now?  I suspect you're asking about something in the ADUC GUI, but I'm not sure.  Nor am I sure what that something might be.  Got a screenshot?

Comment: I guess the OP is talking about the ADUC GUI and computer OU : go there and right-click a computer, select `properties` then select `location` tab : the `Browse` button is greyed out.

Comment: User2196728 is right, that's the form and the button I'm talking about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little-used feature and was primarily meant to be used with printers. If you [enable printer location tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784120(v=ws.10).aspx) you'll see these buttons become available.

(I really wish Microsoft had worked a little harder on this feature. It could have been better-integrated into the client UI and might have made some end-user resource location problems easier to resolve.)

Comment: Weird because I 'apparently' complete all the criteria for the button to become enabled but it's still not the case...

Comment: Nock, do you have rights on the object you're trying to modify? My privileged account gets the button enabled, my unprivileged does not. We use printer location tracking. Evan, Don't think you need that GPO to use "location" button. That GPO setting only handles the "pre-populate" stuff for searching printers.

Answer (score 0):

Change this on your default domain policy (preferably) by going to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Printers -> Pre-Populate printer search location text.  As long as you enter your correct locations and subnets in Active Directory Sites & Services then the browse button will start working.  If you then assign your printers a location when a user goes to add one it will lists those in the current site (subnet) as the user first then let them select a link to list all printers.  We've found it pretty helpful especially with printers named very similarly between sites.